# Windows 10 Desktop and Taskbar not responding after startup

Tags: windows-10, desktop

Recently, it randomly happened a few days ago, where I would boot up my PC and when I click on the taskbar, it will just turn white and say Microsoft wants to kill this process because its not responding. Same goes with the desktop, no icons load, I click on the desktop and it says: explorer.exe is not responding, do you want to kill it.

AFAIK, no viruses are on my computer as I just got it for about a month and the issue started happening a week ago. The desktop icons do load after 5-10 minutes but in that span I can't really do anything because wherever I click, it just stop responds. I think I have a powerful PC so its not the fact that its slow and bottlenecking but here is the specs just in case:

- AMD Ryzen 7 5800X
- 32GB DDR4 RAM
- 1 TB SSD + 2 TB HDD
- GTX 1650 SUPER

Comment: Though I doubt the usefulness of these tips myself, but first update the drivers and try to repair the system using `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` and `sfc /scannow`, maybe if you ware lucky these will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, there is usually an issue with the explorer subsystem or a shell context issue.

I have found the best way to deal with this is to do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

If you have Drop Box running, I suggest you exit from Drop Box before doing a repair install

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.  Normally the first method (Keep Everything) is best but you may need to be more aggressive if method 1 does not work.

> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Comment: If I select (1) keep data, will my settings be gone?

Comment: No.  Method 1 will keep everything . I have done this before.  I always have a good data backup but I have never lost anything.  Method 1 will not fix a damaged User Profile either.